# PHP MySQL update set

Tags: php, mysql, set

I'm trying to update a row, but only to append a new word at **words**:

```
mysql_query("UPDATE list SET words = words', $new_word' WHERE id = $id_row");
```

It's not working, I've no other ideas..

Answer (score 1):

Try with `CONCAT`-

```
"UPDATE list SET words = CONCAT(words, '$new_word') WHERE id = $id_row"
```

Use `mysqli` or `PDO`. `mysql` is deprecated.